# Why display SELECT value is not changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the page load, I expected `<option value="B">B</option>` value to change to red. It didn't work. Why?

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[name=HeaderFields] option[value="B"]').val('red');
});
```

Dropdown:

```
<select name="HeaderFields" style="width:60px">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try this `$('select[name="HeaderFields"] option[value="B"]').val('red').text('red');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val()` sets the *value* of a form field which in a `SELECT` is not the same thing as the *visible text*. This [works correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/6dSQX/1/) for me in Chrome with your example by inspecting the source.

If you are looking to change the visible text, use `html()` or `text()`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/6dSQX/

Answer (score 2):

In an `option` tag, the value property and the displayed-text are two different things.

```
<option value="I am sent to the server">I am displayed to the user</option>
```

So if you want to change the displayed-text, use jQuery's `text` method.

Answer (score 0):

The Value of "B" changes to "red"

not the TEXT.

if you look at the source of the html page you should see

```
<option value="red">B</option>
```

Answer (score -2):

The value change works fine. But if we assume that the font color change is what you mean, you should change your javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[name=HeaderFields] option[value="B"]').css('font-color', 'red');
}
```